# Node.js - Childprocess throws an error but execution of the command in terminal works under OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, package, atom-editor, child-process

I'm developing a package for the editor Atom. The package contains a GUI for python program that only has a CLI. By using my package the user only has to click an icon. The functions are tested well under Windows and it works fine. Now I'm testing all for OS X and the trouble starts.

During the testing I've found some bugs that were fixed by checking the operation system and append the parameter.

I'm using child_process and *exec* or *execSync*.

```
console.log("cmd "+cmd);  //just for whether cmd is correct
child_process.exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        //error handling
        console.log("error.msg "+error.message;
    }else{
     console.log("stdout " +stdout); //just for testing
     console.log("stderr " +stderr); //just for testing
    }
}
```

My issue is that command is executed correct - the python program generates the file but the process throws an error. 
I also tested the command in the terminal and there does not occurs the error. Under Windows I don't have the problems.

Now some more information about the error object:

1. error.message = *Command failed: python_command
   /Users/jDoe/Document/test/test.md*
2. error.code = 119
3. error.killed = false
4. error.stack

   ```
   Error: 
       Command failed: python_command /Users/jDoe/Document/test/test.md
         at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:223:12)
         at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
         at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
         at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit   
       (internal/child_process.js:226:5)"
   ```

The python program could not read locales and return that value was None but I need the encoding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I read the locale and pass them to the process.

```
var env = Object.create( process.env );
env.LANG=`en_US.UTF-8`;  // just for testing 
iExec(cmd, {env: env, cwd: path},
(error, stdout, stderr)  => { 
  if(error){
   // do error handling
  }
});
```

An now it is working fine.